# selenium: How to check if some text is bold or not

Tags: css, selenium

```
<div class="searchCenter largeFont">
<b> 1 </b>
<a href="search/?p=2&q=move&mt=1"> 2 </a>
<a href="search/?p=3&q=move&mt=1"> 3 </a>
<a href="search/?p=4&q=move&mt=1"> 4 </a>
<div> 1 - 10 of 27,600 </div>
</div>
```

how do i check if 1 is bold or not using selenium?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
assertElementPresent(locator)
```

and

```
verifyElementPresent(locator)
```

Will do this for you; e.g. in Selenese you might have:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>xpath=//b[.=" 1 "]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Of course, the bold styling may also be done through CSS, in which case you should make your locator look for a certain class that you know adds a bold styling.

Comment: thanks for the reply..could you please help me with how this would be possible using css locators for the above mentioned example?

Comment: I'm not very good with CSS selectors, here is a good guide: http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/

I *think* that this will work: css=b:contains(' 1 ')